# What's the system account to run ASP.NET web app for each sites in IIS with different application pool?

Tags: asp.net, iis7

Suppose I have many different website created on IIS 7 on Windows 2008 R2.
Each of them may have different application pool:

```
.NET 1.1
.NET 2.0
.NET 3.5
.NET 4.0
```

What the system account to run all those web app? If the app need to read/write file, need to set up right permission for specific folder, then how can I identify the right account to assign right permission?

Answer (score 1):

Each application pool can execute as a specific user to control this do the following:

1. Click on `Application Pools` in IIS Manager
2. Click `Advanced Settings`
3. Find the `Identity` property and click the ellipsis
4. Select the `Custom Account` radio button
5. Enter the user name and password

In step 5 be sure to include the domain name as in: `MyDomain\UserName`

[image: screenshot of each step]